# no such file or directory trying to list or remove file in btrfs

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, directory, btrfs

I have a file system mounted btrfs.  I have one directory in particular, that I can't remove, because it's listed as non-empty.  In that directory, there's one file, which I can see the name of, but no other information.
Here's the output of ls:

```
bminton:/var/spool/exim4/input# ls --escape -la
ls: cannot access '1eumbt-0001A6-KQ-J': No such file or directory
total 0
drwxr-x--- 1 Debian-exim Debian-exim 36 Jul  2 14:41 .
drwxr-x--- 1 Debian-exim Debian-exim 88 Jun 10 05:32 ..
-????????? ? ?           ?            ?            ? 1eumbt-0001A6-KQ-J
```

I tried rm, cp, mv, stat, unlink, etc on the file, including trying `find . -print0 | xargs -0 rm -v` just in case it was a strange filename.  However, everything gives the same error, no such file or directory. (using strace on the unlink process for example, I see the unlink system call returns ENOENT).

I ran `btrfs scrub start .`, which ran, and waited until `btrfs scrub status .` showed it as finished, with 0 errors.  Is there any way to manually remove the directory entry?

Comment: Assuming the directory you want to delete is `/var/spool/exim4/input`, try a forced delete on the directory: `rm -f /var/spool/exim4/input`

Comment: I tried that too, @EmmanuelRosa.  `bminton:/var/spool/exim4# rm -rf input
rm: cannot remove 'input': Directory not empty`